# Migration from SVN code to Star Team

Tags: tortoisesvn, starteam

My developer are using SVN code repository. The project is in production state.

we are planning to migrate SVN to STAR TEAM.  I mean takeing the code dump to svn and migrate the previous svn code to STAR TEAM.

Can any one guide me how to proceed this task.

FYI:  We have installed the STAR team client application.

Waiting for your reply.

Comment: you need a starteam server as well

Comment: Everyone seems to be going the other way round, quite unusual you are moving into Starteam at this stage, anyway see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219401/is-there-an-easy-way-to-do-a-complete-migration-from-cvs-to-starteam

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way, though you really will want to script it out, is to create projects in StarTeam that match your projects in SVN.  For each project, you need to iterate through all of the objects under source contorol and for each one, start with the oldest revision of the object and check that into StarTeam (most likely using the StarTeam command line interface) including the comments on the object from SVN.  You would proceed up the timeline until you get to the most current object.

Here is a short summary of doing this to convert from CVS to StarTeam.  You would follow a similar approach: http://www.foxdata.com/starteam/faq/how_to_migrate_cvs_archives_to_starteam.htm